# Is it possible for a power series of the form $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$ to conditionally converge on both of its endpoints?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I've been thinking about this for a while and haven't been able to come up with an example that fits this case specifically. When I was working on this I had tried to first consider the simplest case possible where the endpoints are one and negative one. In this case one would find that $\sum a_{n}$ and $\sum (-1)^{n}a_{n}$ must both conditionally converge for this to be true. However, I am having trouble finding any sort of $a_{n}$ that would make this true. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $$1+\frac12x-\frac13x^2-\frac14x^3+\frac15x^4+\frac16x^5-\frac17x^6-\frac18x^7+\cdots\ ?$$

Comment: @bof Is this a pair of arctangent-like power series added together? (This was an idea I stumbled on right as you posted this. Nice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) mentions an interesting series due to Sierpinski with a stronger property: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i x^i, \quad \text{where} \quad a_i = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n n} \; \text{if} \; 2^{n-1} \le i < 2^n,$$ i.e. $$\frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} - \frac{x^3}{8} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{x^5}{24} + \frac{x^6}{24} + \frac{x^7}{24} - \frac{x^8}{64} - ...$$ converges conditionally everywhere on the unit circle but never absolutely (by divergence of the harmonic series).